# Using React Browser history push gives strange error duplicate Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I learn react and I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/masonry-forked-715od?file=/src/sections/RadionButtons.js) for this problem

On the top screen there are two buttons that suppose to show Foto Album 1 and 2.
Default is Album 1.
Pressing Button Album 2 show the album but also it creates a new Component so there are two gallerys

I follow tutorial for React History but I must have missed something right please advice.
The TimeLineViewer.js is the Gallery holding a Masonry style Gallery

Is it the call to:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: "/timeLineViewer",
  state: { week: "1" }
});
```

That injects a new Gallery under existing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a single route 'timelineViewer' for both albums, you don't need to push a new route.

You can create a handler for changing album, pass it to RadioButtons as props and pass the selection result to TimelineViewer.

It is natural to have 2 components of TimelineViewer, because of this code snippet.

```
        <div>
          <RadionButtons />
          <TimeLineViewer />
        </div>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/timeLineViewer" component={TimeLineViewer} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks I know React Redux and about to use it but this app is stateless so I though I just could route some. But how to create a handler for changing album? I'm an Android developer, java, C++ but Understand React overall only

Comment: Thanks @Hayden Did you fork my Sandbox? Can you give me link?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the fork link, I don't know how to find it again. :(

Comment: I found it. https://codesandbox.io/s/masonry-forked-yqxx6

Comment: This Gallery you help me with will be used [here](http://greta.portplays.com/),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219765/discussion-between-hayden-s-and-exocetkid).